# Should "knowledge" be, or not be, followed by "about"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have the below construction and doubting the correct usage of prepositions.

> This paper shows a comprehensive approach that takes into account the
>   *knowledge* ***about*** the shape of man-made object for individual object segmentation from point data.

Do you think that I should use *about* with *knowledge*? Any rectifications please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this context *knowledge* should be followed either by *about* or *of*, because the sentence specifies a particular field of knowledge.

Also, you should have an article in front of *man-made object* (or use the plural form *objects*).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is similar to the following ones:

> He has a wide **knowledge of** painting and music.

> There is a lack of **knowledge about** the tax system.

In both the cases, you cannot remove *of/about*.

> *?* He has a wide **knowledge** painting and music.